# hc off canvas merge double menu

Tags: html, jquery, css

How to apply "hc off-canvas nav" to two menus with logo in the middle.

https://jsfiddle.net/Murat_Kartal/gbk4dhyx/36/ `Example`

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the expected results? Should the logo be visible on mobile? Where?

Comment: Actually, the problem is not the logo, but the menu links to the right and left of the logo appear on two separate hc off canvas panels. Thanks for your answer.